# MySQL slow query: order by datetime

Tags: mysql, performance, date, sql-order-by

i have a table with about 5kk records

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `termo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' on update     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sensor` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `temp` float NOT NULL default '-255'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=5466795 ;
```

indexes

```
ALTER TABLE `termo` ADD PRIMARY KEY  (`id`), ADD KEY `date_3` (`date`,`sensor`);
```

query

```
select pressure, humidity, temp_a, voltage, aqua_temp, home_temp, home_hum, current from
(select temp as pressure from termo force index(date_3) where sensor='000461965E3901' order by date desc limit 0,1) as pressure,
(select temp as humidity from termo force index(date_3) where sensor='000461965E3903' order by date desc limit 0,1) as humidity,
(select temp as temp_a from termo force index(date_3) where sensor='000461965E3902' order by date desc limit 0,1) as temp_a,
(select temp as voltage from termo force index(date_3) where sensor='000461965E3904' order by date desc limit 0,1) as voltage,
(select temp as aqua_temp from termo force index(date_3) where sensor='000461965E3907' order by date desc limit 0,1) as aqua_temp,
(select temp as home_temp from termo force index(date_3) where sensor='000461965E3905' order by date desc limit 0,1) as home_temp,
(select temp as current from termo force index(date_3) where sensor='000461965E3911' order by date desc limit 0,1) as current,
(select temp as home_hum from termo force index(date_3) where sensor='000461965E3906' order by date desc limit 0,1) as home_hum
```

works very slow... about 30 seconds.
please help optimize.

explain looks like

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  system  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   
1   PRIMARY     <derived3>  system  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   
1   PRIMARY     <derived4>  system  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   
1   PRIMARY     <derived5>  system  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   
1   PRIMARY     <derived6>  system  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   
1   PRIMARY     <derived7>  system  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   
1   PRIMARY     <derived8>  system  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   
1   PRIMARY     <derived9>  system  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   
9   DERIVED     termo   index   NULL    date_3  3232    NULL    5193950     Using where

8   DERIVED     termo   index   NULL    date_3  3232    NULL    5193950     Using where

7   DERIVED     termo   index   NULL    date_3  3232    NULL    5193950     Using where

6   DERIVED     termo   index   NULL    date_3  3232    NULL    5193950     Using where

5   DERIVED     termo   index   NULL    date_3  3232    NULL    5193950     Using where

4   DERIVED     termo   index   NULL    date_3  3232    NULL    5193950     Using where

3   DERIVED     termo   index   NULL    date_3  3232    NULL    5193950     Using where

2   DERIVED     termo   index   NULL    date_3  3232    NULL    5193950     Using where
```

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: if a higher id every time also a newer date ?

Comment: use IN() instead of all this selects

Comment: btw, if you need use `force index()` maybe you should check why optimizer isnt using it on his own. Very intelligent ppl work in make a good optimizer, and if he isnt using index there is probably a reason for it.

Comment: @sagi maybe you could write that select? I dont see how `IN()` can help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be a better way, but need add `INDEX` for only `sensor` so `IN` statement work faster.

```
SELECT termo.`sensor`, `temp`
FROM termo
JOIN (
    SELECT `sensor`, MAX(`date`) as `lastTemp`
    FROM termo 
    WHERE sensor IN ('000461965E3901', '000461965E3903', '000461965E3902',
                     '000461965E3904', '000461965E3907', '000461965E3905',
                     '000461965E3911', '000461965E3906')
    GROUP BY sensor
    ) T
 ON termo.`date` = T.`lastTemp`
AND termo.`sensor` = T.`sensor`
```

Also consider test with a composite `INDEX (temp, date, sensor)`

To get the right label use

```
SELECT 
   MAX(CASE WHEN termo.sensor = '000461965E3901' THEN temp END) as pressure,
   MAX(CASE WHEN termo.sensor = '000461965E3903' THEN temp END) as humidity ,
   MAX(CASE WHEN termo.sensor = '000461965E3902' THEN temp END) as temp_a,
   MAX(CASE WHEN termo.sensor = '000461965E3904' THEN temp END) as voltage ,
   MAX(CASE WHEN termo.sensor = '000461965E3907' THEN temp END) as aqua_temp ,
   MAX(CASE WHEN termo.sensor = '000461965E3905' THEN temp END) as home_temp ,
   MAX(CASE WHEN termo.sensor = '000461965E3911' THEN temp END) as current ,
   MAX(CASE WHEN termo.sensor = '000461965E3906' THEN temp END) as home_hum
FROM termo
JOIN (
    SELECT `sensor`, MAX(`date`) as `lastTemp`
    FROM termo 
    WHERE sensor IN ('000461965E3901', '000461965E3903', '000461965E3902',
                     '000461965E3904', '000461965E3907', '000461965E3905',
                     '000461965E3911', '000461965E3906')
    GROUP BY sensor
    ) T
 ON termo.`date` = T.`lastTemp`
AND termo.`sensor` = T.`sensor`
```

Comment: try now. just add the name of the table

Comment: well 10 seconds isnt bad :)

Answer (score 0):

try to modify each subselect like this. i know its not the best way. i will send a shorter query later.

`(SELECT temp AS pressure FROM termo WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM termo WHERE sensor='000461965E3901'))`

and add a key

```
ALTER TABLE `termo`  ADD KEY `sensor` (`sensor`);
```

Comment: Query took 91.5878 seconds.

Comment: do you have add the key ? ALTER TABLE `termo`  ADD KEY `sensor` (`sensor`);

Comment: yes :) ALTER TABLE termo ADD PRIMARY KEY (id), ADD KEY sensor (sensor);